# A question concerning model theory of groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, profinite-groups

Several days ago, Professor Martin Bridson gave a very nice talk in my department. Some questions concerning his talk came into my brain  Since I am neither a model theorist nor a algebraist, I am not sure whether they fit here or not.

**Question 1. Given a finite group $Q$, is there a sentence $\varphi$ in the group language so that for any group $G$, $G\models \varphi$ if and only if there is a surjective homomorphism  from $G$ to $Q$?**

Now let $G$ be a residually finite group and the corresponded inverse system $A=\{G/N\mid G/N \mbox{ is finite}\}$. Define $\hat{\Gamma}$ to be the inverse limit of $A$. Martin only focused on countable group and he mentioned that there is a quite important conjecture which says that for any two countable residually finite  groups $G_0$ and $G_1$, $\hat{G_0}\cong\hat{G_1}\implies G_0\cong G_1$.Now I have the following question.

**Question 2. Is it true that for arbitrary residually finite  groups $G_0$ and $G_1$ (they do not need to be countable), $\hat{G_0}\cong\hat{G_1}\implies G_0\equiv G_1$, where $\equiv$ means elementary equivalence relation?**

I am also interested the relationship between $G$ and $\hat{G}$. For example, $G\equiv_1 \hat{G}?$, where $\equiv_1$ means that they satisfy exactly same $\Sigma_1$-formulas?

Comment: You would at least want your group to be residually finite for the second question since the profinite completion of any infinite simple group is isomorphic to the profinite completion of the trivial group.

Comment: Do you mean homemorphism, or homomorphism? In the former case you'd need a topology, and you probably want to the take discrete one, in which case you just mean isomorphism, and in that case the answer is trivially yes. Just write the multiplication table of $Q$. In the latter case, you probably want it to be surjective, or at least nontrivial, otherwise every group has a trivial homomorphism into $Q$, so trivially $\exists x(x=x)$ works.

Comment: Semidirect products $\mathbf{Z}/11\mathbf{Z}\rtimes_2\mathbf{Z}$ and $\mathbf{Z}/11\mathbf{Z}\rtimes_8\mathbf{Z}$ are non-isomorphic with isomorphic profinite completion. I don't know if they are elementary equivalent.

Comment: @Asaf, I meant  homomorphism. A typo. Thanks.

Comment: Then probably a non-triviality condition is also needed there.

Comment: @Benjamin. Ah, you are right. They should be residually finite.

Comment: @Ycor. Thanks for the counterexample. Now I understand why he is only interested in residually finite groups.

Comment: You misunderstand me. These groups are residually finite. On the other hand I don't claim that they are not elementary equivalent (probably they are, since we can't expect such simple counterexamples for a conjecture).

Comment: Thanks.   Maybe they are not elementary equivalent either.

Comment: would you remind what is $\Sigma_1$-formula?

Comment: Do we know whether the property of "surjecting homomorphically onto $Q$" is invariant under the ultrapower construction? That is, is it true that: $G$ surjects homomorphically onto $Q$ if and only if every ultrapower $G^I/U$ surjects homomorphically onto $Q$?

Comment: It's very likely false, even when $Q$ has order 2. We'd need one group $G$ in which every element is a product of squares, but for no $n$ every element is a product of $n$ squares.

Comment: The examples I mentioned with $Z/11$ are indeed elementary equivalent EE. Indeed Oger (1982 http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=689074, Théorème 5.5) proved that two finite-by-abelian f.g. groups $G,H$ (I mean, finite kernel, abelian quotient) are EE iff their profinite completions are isomorphic as topological groups  (with other characterizations, e.g., that is equivalent to: $G\times\mathbf{Z}$ and $H\times\mathbf{Z}$ are isomorphic groups). (Note that abstract homomorphisms between top. f.g. profinite groups are continuous, by Nikolov-Segal, which is easy in this special setting).

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the open question. As @YCor says, there are non-isomorphic residually finite groups with isomorphic profinite completions. The question is open when $G_0$ and $G_1$ are Kleinian groups, or when $G_0$ is free and $G_1$ is residually finite.

Comment: @HJRW, thanks. I have no his slides, probably I misunderstood the question. Anyway, it's good to know the facts discussed above.